# Javascript onclick function does not display text assigned

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display the text using javascript with the onclick function.

i) When I click on both button it only displays the red color , not the blue one.

ii) As well as, when I click on red button 1st time then it displays the red color and if I choose the red button again then it displays the blue color.

```js
function myFunction() {


  if (document.getElementById("demo").value == "11") {
    document.getElementById("flight").innerHTML = "<p style='color:red'>Red Color</p>";
  }

  if (document.getElementById("demo").value == "22") {
    document.getElementById("flight").innerHTML = "<p style='color:blue'>Blue Color</p>";
  }

}
```

```html
<button id="demo" onclick="myFunction()" value="11">Red</button>
<button id="demo" onclick="myFunction()" value="22">Blue</button>
<div id="flight"></div>
```

Comment: `id`s should be unique

Comment: You've got duplicate ids..

Comment: I think this question should be deleted...OP just didn't do any debugging (with this little code, to miss duplicate IDs = not debugging effectively)

Comment: I'm not going to downvote but people with high reps providing answers for this question is just amazing IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the comments, an ID *should* be unique. Otherwise, it will screw up your JS.

I suggest you pass the current DOM element to your function, and use it like so:

```js
function myFunction(elem) {
  switch(elem.getAttribute('value')) {
    case "11":
      document.getElementById("flight").innerHTML = "<p style='color:red'>Red</p>";
      break;
    case "22":
      document.getElementById("flight").innerHTML = "<p style='color:blue'>Blue</p>";
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" value="11">Red</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" value="22">Blue</button>
<div id="flight"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ids need to be unique in your document. The browser always only recognizes the first button with id *flight* and discards the id of the second for this reason.

---

Instead, you could solve the problem with multiple event handlers:

```js
function displayRed() {
  document.getElementById("flight").innerHTML = "<p style='color:red'>Red Color</p>";
}

function displayBlue() {
  document.getElementById("flight").innerHTML = "<p style='color:blue'>Blue Color</p>";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="displayRed()" value="11">Red</button>
<button onclick="displayBlue()" value="22">Blue</button>
<div id="flight"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Html :

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" value="11">Red</button>

<button onclick="myFunction(this)" value="22">Blue</button>

<div id="flight"> </div>
```

JavaScript :

```
function myFunction(x) {

if (x.value == "11")
 document.getElementById("flight").innerHTML = "<p style='color:red'>Red Color</p>";

else if (x.value == "22")
   document.getElementById("flight").innerHTML = "<p style='color:blue'>Blue Color</p>";

}
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<button class="demo" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="11">Red</button>
<button class="demo" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="22">Blue</button>
<div id="flight"> </div>

<script>
    
function myFunction(x) {
    
    if (x.value == "11")
            document.getElementById("flight").innerHTML = "<p style='color:red'>Red Color</p>";
    
    else if (x.value == "22")
       document.getElementById("flight").innerHTML = "<p style='color:blue'>Blue Color</p>";

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```